# Получение json-ответа от сайта для парсинга

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Пытаюсь получить json-ответ от сайта https://1xstavka.ru/results/.

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://1xstavka.ru/results/'
params = {'showAll': 'true', 'date': '2020-04-08'}
rs = requests.get(url, params=params)
print(rs.json())
```

В инструментах разработчика в ответа видно, что на get-запрос есть json-ответ, в котором вся нужная информация. Но, после выполнения кода, всегда приходит ответ в виде text/html. Добавление заголовков, тоже не помогает.
Подскажите, как сформировать запрос, чтобы вытащить json с сайта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, если смотреть в инструментах разработчика, url запроса не `https://1xstavka.ru/results/`, а `https://1xstavka.ru/results/getmain`. Но если делать get запрос через requests на этот url, то возвращает 404 ошибку.

Если еще раз посмотреть в инструментах разработчика заголовки запроса, там можно увидеть параметр `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`:

[image: Скриншот]

Методом перебора определил, что именно этого параметра не хватает, чтобы приходил json ответ. Соответственно, нужно добавить этот параметр в заголовки:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://1xstavka.ru/results/getmain'
params = {'showAll': 'true', 'date': '2020-04-30'}
headers = {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
rs = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
print(rs.json())
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогло!